# Installing SphinxQL in Php

Tags: php, namespaces, sphinx, sphinxql

I followed all the steps in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide, and have successfully installed Sphinx on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. However, I am not able to use SphinxQL (by Foolz) in my php pages. This is the code I am using :

```
<?php

use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
 
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 9306));
 
$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)
->select('*')
->from('documents')
->match('desc', 'testing');
 

$result = $query->execute();
```

This gives me a "**Fatal error: Class 'Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection' not found**".

Sphinx is installed in the `/etc/sphinxsearch/` directory.

Comment: Did you use composer to install https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder ? Ie so can use composer autoload?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I did!

Comment: Im fairly certain this has something to do with the namespace... I've tried multiple options, all of them lead to class not found :\

Comment: Have you actually setup the autoloader? https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Apologies for the delay, and yes I followed all instructions on that page. Im not too familiar with composer, so I'm not entirely sure how to debug this either

Comment: Does the actual sphinx installation need to be in the project folder?

Comment: Look at the bootstrap file: https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php it shows how to use autoload.php

Comment: Hello, did you try `<?php print_r(get_declared_classes());` ? That way you will know for sure whether the classes you're importing are declared. Sounds to me you didn't add `<?php require_once __DIR__ . 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: The problem is on PHP side, specifically with the autoloader. It does not matter how you installed Sphinxsearch at this point.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem. For me the autoloader (function findFileWithExtension)  is trying to find the file at    /mnt/i/var/www/vhosts/my.play.net/sphinx/vendor/composer/../foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/Connection.php when it should presumably be looking in /mnt/i/var/www/vhosts/my.play.net/sphinx/vendor/composer/../foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/Drivers/Mysqli/Connection.php ?